# Methodology: how to change URL without reloading page and index whole URL (with anchor # part)?

Tags: php, javascript, python, html, backend

I need Google indexes full URL with anchor part (http://example.com#!/1234).

User enters on http://example.com/. Then he click a reference and the address of the page changes to http://example.com#!/1234 (something happens, page does not reload). If user types the address (http://example.com#!/1234) directly to address line of a browser and presses *Enter* then corresponding page loads. It may have differencies from http://example.com (it looks like user has done the action of clicking).

In this case Google can index http://example.com#!/1234 as independent resource.

How to provide the behavior? We have Javascript and any backend language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation here: http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html

And specifically the parts relating to `_escaped_fragment_`.